# symfony can't install assets the first time

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I try to install a db and a web server with docker compose.

my docker-compose file is :

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: pix_db
    container_name: pix_db
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    networks:
    - backend
  api:
    image: pix_api
    container_name: pix_api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfiles/api/Dockerfile.cpu
    depends_on:
    - media
    - db
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    networks:
    - backend

networks:
  backend:
  hidden:

volumes:
  db_data:
```

When I reach this line in my docker file :

```
php bin/console assets:install -e prod
```

It crash with several error like :

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

When I build the container from the line before : 
The command `php bin/console assets:install -e prod` crash with the same error the first time I call it. 
but the second time it success with :

```
Installing assets as hard copies.

--- ----------------------------- ----------------
      Bundle                        Method / Error
--- ----------------------------- ----------------
  ✔   NelmioApiDocBundle            copy
      -> web/bundles/nelmioapidoc
  ✔   AppBundle                     copy
      -> web/bundles/app
--- ----------------------------- ----------------

! [NOTE] Some assets were installed via copy. If you make changes to these assets you have to run this command again.


[OK] All assets were successfully installed.
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the DB during build time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to access the DB during image building itself. Each image is build individually and when the image is being it doesn't have access to any running services like mysql DB or anything.

So if you use something like `php bin/console assets:install -e prod` which will connect to DB then it won't work. You need to execute command in such a way that DB is not called or you need to delay the commands till the starting of the container.

For example if you look at the mysql image. It doesn't init the DB during build. It uses a `docker-entrypoint.sh` to build the blank DB also on container start. See the link below

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/0590e4efd2b31ec794383f084d419dea9bc752c4/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh

So you need to follow similar approach and create a `entrypoint.sh` script which will be run once the container starts and it will build these assets and others things for you. You also want to make sure that before you run the commands the mysql container is completely up and ready to accept DB connection.

I usually add sleep 15 or so before initialization. But you can use something like https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it also.

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer is still true, there is another option: **setting the server version in your configuration**. If it's not set, Symfony (more exactly Doctrine\DBAL) tries to connect to your database to find out which server version is used.

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        server_version: 'mariadb-10.9.4'
```

Please read the configuration reference about DBAL in [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration).

Also see https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/681#issuecomment-65768410